# Manter item do menu desabilitado

Tags: html

Como manter um ítem do menu temporariamente desabilitado no site?

```
<li><a href='cadastrar.php'>CADASTRAR</a></li>
```

Grato.

Comment: Se possível, poste o código que você possui até agora, HTML ou javascript, e em qual situação ele deveria ser habilitado/desabilitado.

Comment: <li><a href="cadastrar.php">CADASTRAR</a></li>

Comment: Quero desabilitá-lo temporariamente, até a pagina ser consolidada.

Comment: Cara é só tirar o link do LI e fazer um CSS qualquer pro Cadastro. `<li style="color:#ddd;">CADASTRAR</li> ` Sua pergunta não está muito clara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível desabilitar a ação padrão por *JavaScript*.

Com jQuery:

```
$("a[href='cadastrar.php']").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Com JavaScript nativo:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='cadastrar.php']");

el[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer isso com css e deixando sem link dentro do "href":

```css
.link{
cursor:auto;
}
```

```html
<li><a class="link" href='#'>CADASTRAR</a></li>
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos! Agora, como sinalizar ? Quais das 3 primeiras opções devo clicar?